# touch screen path made on the screen is shrinking as the screen size is increasing

Tags: swift, swift2

I am using this code to draw the touch path on the screen but as the size of screen is increasing, the touch path is not staying stable. Could anyone offer a suggestion?

Path drawn on 6S

Path drawn on 4S

```
func draw(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.subImageView.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    subImageView?.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: subImageView.frame.width, height: subImageView.frame.height))
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x, end.y)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    subImageView.image = newImage

}
```

Comment: add images again please

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the fact that on 4S the screen is 2x, while on6S the screen is 3x.Due to the way you create your image context, the image is not taking that into account and always has 1x size.
Try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.subImageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.subImageView.frame.size)`

Comment: @John  could you accept the answer if it solved your issue?